# REPL console application service

Tags: linux, service, console

I hope this is the right forum for this, and excuse the naive question.

I would like to provide an "guest" login to a (non-dedicated) linux server and run just one console application. The user cannot do anything more than use this application. A scenario could be:

```
      ssh dervinATsomehost.com (no password)
```

and the just automatically execute the shell app, say

```
       Welcome to Dervin's shell.
       Dervin$
```

when the user says exit, the whole connection would drop, not just the application.

This seems relatively simple, but I wouldn't know where to start.

Thanks.

[**NOTE** I've posted this on Serverfault also. Did not know which forum was the best. Feel free to close if it's not pertinent.]

Comment: Choose one or the other, if it belongs on the other site it will be migrated there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the desired application as the user's shell in `/etc/passwd`.

So when the user logs in, instead of `bash` session they get straight into the application.

Comment: Yep, this is the most secure, and is often used by professional hosters as well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess first you'd want to pick a language to work in. Something with a code-evaluation function like Scheme's `eval` make the "E" part of REPL easier. Other than that, it's just reading user input and printing the results of the evaluation(s). Then looping, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You'll definitely want to distribute ssh keys to everyone, or, have them generate their own, and give those to you.  Add the program you want executed to the list in /etc/shells, and use chsh on those users to change their shell to that program.